# Parse Users make and join groups in app

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have an app that uses Parse.com as the backend. I have the login successfully working. But now I want users to be able to create and join groups within the app. Then I also want them to be able to chat with the group but my main concern is just having them be able to create and join. What is the best way to go about this? Is there a tutorial for it I could go off of?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't. Parse is a horrible platform to build off, as you may know Apple just released CloudKit at WWDC. Use this. I was going to initially use Parse and it was hard to get anything done, and it took me a few weeks to get one of my tasks done. At WWDC my team and I got almost the entire app done in one day with CloudKit

Comment: Is there a good tutorial I could go off of to get started with CloudKit? I'm still relatively new to programming. I just did research on cloudkit and I agree you are right, that is the way to go. But I am having trouble finding how to implement it.

Comment: Documentation. Documentation. Documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CloudKit_Framework_Reference/ also if this helped you. ;) up vote my answer